# How to configure DORA metrics to Jenkins and Gitlab?

Tags: jenkins, gitlab, devops, metrics

I tried to understand the DORA metrics but i didn't get more about this configuration and tool details.

I need a configuration and prerequisite details.

Comment: What is missing in https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/analytics/dora_metrics.html ?

Comment: how to setup with GitLab? I have doubt it is separate tool or one of the processes.

If it is one of the processes of tools, then how to implement?

Comment: It is set up by default with GitLab Premium or Ultimate. You can see examples in [this PDF document](https://docs.developer.tech.gov.sg/docs/ship-hats-getting-started/files/DevOps-Metrics-with-GitLab.pdf).

Comment: Thank you. I got it.
Then how to configure Dora metrics in Jenkins?

Comment: On Jenkins side, this is more [about calling GitLab DORA API](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/blob/master/doc/api/dora/metrics.md). Even though... GitLab prefers you would be [migrating from Jenkins to GitLab](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/migration/jenkins.html)!.

Answer (score 0):

As I commented, this is only for GitLab Ultimate, but, in addition of "[**DevOps Research and Assessment (DORA) metrics**](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/analytics/dora_metrics.html)", you now (May 2023) also have, with [GitLab 16.0](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2023/05/22/gitlab-16-0-released/#custom-value-streams-for-project-level-value-stream-analytics) (May 2023):

> ### Custom value streams for project-level value stream analytics
>
> To improve the visibility into the complete workstream, we are adding to the project-level Value Stream Analytics (VSA) the [Overview stage](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/group/value_stream_analytics) and the option to [create custom value streams](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/group/value_stream_analytics/#create-a-value-stream-with-custom-stages).
>
> Until now, these features were only available at the group-level VSA only.
>
> [image: https://about.gitlab.com/images/16_0/16_vsaparity.gif -- Custom value streams for project-level value stream analytics]
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/group/value_stream_analytics/) and [Issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/382496).

You can call [DORA metrics API](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/blob/master/doc/api/dora/metrics.md) from a Jenkins job.
Or... directly [migrate from Jenkins](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/migration/jenkins.html) and use GitLab CI/CD!

---

And [GitLab 16.8](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2024/01/18/gitlab-16-8-released/#new-organization-level-devops-view-with-dora-based-industry-benchmarks) (January 2024) adds:

> ### New organization-level DevOps view with DORA-based industry benchmarks
>
> We added a new **DORA Performers score** panel to the [Value Streams Dashboard](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EA9Sbks27g4) to visualize the status of the organization’s DevOps performance across different projects. This new visualization displays a breakdown of the DORA score (high, medium, or low) so that executives can understand the organization’s DevOps health top to bottom.
>
> The [four DORA metrics](https://about.gitlab.com/solutions/value-stream-management/dora/#overview) are available out-of-the-box in GitLab, and now with the new DORA scores organizations can compare their DevOps performance against [industry benchmarks](https://dora.dev/) or peers. This benchmarking helps executives understand where they stand in relation to others, and identify best practices or areas where they might be lagging behind.
>
> To help us improve the Value Streams Dashboard, please share feedback about your experience in this [survey](https://gitlab.fra1.qualtrics.com/jfe/form/SV_50guMGNU2HhLeT4).
>
> [image: https://about.gitlab.com/images/16_8/16.8_vsd_dora.png -- New organization-level DevOps view with DORA-based industry benchmarks]
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/analytics/value_streams_dashboard.html#dora-performers-score-panel) and [Issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/426516).